# Prevent two types from overlapping in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I have the following declaration in `Array.ts` that act as helper types and declarations for `Array<T>.flat()` and `Array<T>.flatDeep()`.

```ts
export {}

type ElementType<T> = T extends (infer U)[] ? U : T;
type JaggedArrayItem<T> = T | JaggedArray<T>;
type JaggedElementType<T> = T extends JaggedArray<infer U> ? U : T;
interface JaggedArray<T> extends Array<JaggedArrayItem<T>> { }

declare global {
    interface Array<T> {
        /**
         * Flattens the array one level, removing empty elements.  Does not flatten recursively.
         *
         * @example
         * [1, [2, 3]].flat() // => [1, 2, 3]
         *
         * @example
         * [[1, [2, 3], [4, [5]]], 6].flat() // => [1, 2, 3, 4, [5], 6]
         *
         * @example
         * let arr = new Array(3);
         * arr[0] = 1;
         * arr[2] = undefined;
         *
         * arr.flat() // => [1, undefined]
         */
        flat(): ElementType<T>[];

        /**
         * Flattens the array recursively.  Removes empty elements.
         *
         * @example
         * [1, [2, 3]].flatDeep() // => [1, 2, 3]
         *
         * @example
         * [[1, [2, 3], [4, [5]]], 6].flatDeep() // => [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
         *
         * @example
         * let arr = new Array(3);
         * arr[0] = 1;
         * arr[2] = undefined;
         *
         * arr.flatDeep() // => [1, undefined]
         */
        flatDeep(this: JaggedArray<T>): JaggedElementType<T>[];
    }
}
```

`Array<T>.flat()` only flattens one depth of the array, while `Array<T>.flatDeep()` flattens the entire thing.

```ts
[1, [2, [3]]].flat() // => [1, 2, [3]]
[1, [2, [3]]].flatDeep() // => [1, 2, 3]
```

When I compile this, however, I *sometimes* get an error:

> Return type annotation circularly references itself.

What's odd is that I only get this sometimes.  Sometimes it compiles fine.  Even when it compiles fine, however, this error appears in the generated `Array.d.ts` file.

If I only declare one of `ElementType<T>` and `JaggedElementType<T>`, then the respective function compiles fine, but obviously the other function does not.

The issue is that `JaggedElementType` is a superset of `ElementType`.

How do I prevent these from overlapping?

Answer (score 1):

After a couple hours of finagling (and *right* before I was about to click the post button on this question) I figured it out, so I thought I'd write my own answer.

The trick is, in `ElementType<T>` detect whether `T` extends `JaggedArray<T>`, and if so, it isn't an `ElementType`.  We do this by using the `never` keyword.

```ts
type ElementType<T> = 
    T extends JaggedArray<T> ? never : 
    T extends Array<infer U> ? U : 
    T;
```